Link incoming call to outboud Dial in Twilio
I have a Twilio number that outside users can call. I then use the dial verb to connect that call to an "internal" number in order to record the call and use the chat bot that is connected to the internal number.
I need to pass the call SID (or some variable) of the first call, to the second one created by the Dial verb. Basically, I just need to link the 2 calls together since the recording is linked to the 1st call SID and all the other activities are linked to the 2nd call SID>

In looking at the logs, I see that I have 3 SIDs for each "call". There is 1 for the initial incoming call. There is a 2nd one for the dial verb (outgoing) and then the 3rd for the incoming call from the dial. I need to link the 1st SID with the 3rd. I don't see any link between 2 and 3. there is a parent/child link between 1 and 2, but I don't see anything to connect to the 3rd call.
